# Registry Export doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, registry, system.diagnostics

I tried this code to export a registry key to a file.

```
private void BackupRegistry()
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    Process.Start("reg", string.Format("export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\DownloadManager {0}\\idm.reg", dir));
}
```

but when I execute the method there isn't any idm.reg in executable dir.

Comment: UAC prevents writing files to the same directory as the install location of a program.  You'll need to pick a better directory, use Environment.GetFolderPath() or Path.GetTempFileName().

Comment: @HansPassant UAC is disable in my laptop!

Comment: @HansPassant How about `backups` directory in the `dir` path? I tried that but that didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enquote the path if it contains whitespaces

```
private void BackupRegistry()
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    Process.Start("reg", string.Format("export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\DownloadManager \"{0}\\idm.reg\"", dir));
}
```